# Visual Studio 2017 - UWP App - "ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml

I created a simple Hello World application (UWP) in VS 2017. The application has one button that does nothing (the button is only visible when selected in the Design window). The apps debugs fine but throws an exception when loading the designer window. The Exception

> "***ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range***"

with the stack trace:

> *at Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.XamlUIPresenter.Present()    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.Views.UwpImageHost.HardwarePresentWorker(D3DImageWrapper
>   bitmapWrapper)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.Views.UwpImageHost.PresentWorker(BitmapWrapper
>   bitmapWrapper)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.Views.UwpImageHost.RenderScheduler.CompositionTarget_Rendering(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler).*

Creating a similar app in VS 2015 does not throw any exceptions.

Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Version 15.3.2
Windows 10 Anniversary Edition Build 14393 (Target and Min Version)
.NET 4.6.2

Comment: Have you updated all your nuget packages to the latest?

Comment: All the nuget packages are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair Visual Studio from Visual Studio Installer

And make sure that you update all your nuget packages to latest update